# Line appears under image in VSE

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor

When I add an image to a video in Blender, a thin white line appears under it at the bottom border, and stays there no matter how much I translate the image.  I checked the image to make sure it wasn't part of that.  It's there a reason for this?

Comment: Could you upload a blendfile (with the image packed)? It's hard to say what might be causing this. Without more info we can't do much more than speculate.

Comment: Does the image have an alpha channel? Does the line show up in the final rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use blener 2.7a. I had the same problem. but only if I use "Image Crop" function and sRGB as "Input Color". The thin line you referring to is 2 pixels in height, one pixel above bottom, so the last line of pixel remains sound, right? Checking "Convert Float" under "Filter" resolved the problem for the above settings on my system! Although I do not really know, what it does. Hope this helps...
Besides, my input-file is MTS from Lumix GH2.